# Calculate $0+3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Calculate $0 + 3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$**

Right solution: $0 + 3 = 0$ 
But should not it be $0 + 3= 3 ≡ -4 \pmod 7$?

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The notation might be confusing; $\mathbb{Z}_7$ might refer to $7$-adic integers. In which case, $0 + 3 = 3$.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Is this from a book? Indeed, $0+3 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$.

Comment: It's the same since $-4\equiv 3\mod 7$.

Comment: yeah , its from a exercise from my book. its just tell me to calculate 0+3 in Z7.

Comment: In every ring, $0 + x = x$.  It can't be $0$, unless $x =0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that you are working in the field $(\mathbb Z_7,+,\cdot)$, where $+$ is addition modulo $7$ and $\cdot$ is multiplication modulo $7$.

We have $\mathbb Z_7=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

So if you are asked to calculate something in $\mathbb Z_7$, it is quite reasonable to give as a result some of the seven numbers which belong to $\mathbb Z_7$.

In this case the result is $3$. (Since $0+3=3$ and the remainder of $3$ modulo $7$ is $3$.)

---

However, we still can say that $-4$ is a correct answer in this sense: In any field we denote by $-a$ the additive inverse of $a$. Since $3+4=0$ in $\mathbb Z_7$, the number $4$ is indeed the additive inverse of $3$. So, with this notation, we have $-4=3$.

Comment: awesome , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As, you have tagged it with ring theory, note that in the ring $\mathbb Z_7$, the primary binary operation is addition modulo $7$. Thus $0+3=0\pmod 7+3\pmod7=3\pmod7$. And $3$ indeed is a member of the ring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well :)